# switch display turning back when switching pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a switch based on a something I found online, and it gave me some problems along the way. When I press the switch to the "on" state, the variable that it should change is changed properly, and the switch is also displaying that it is in the right mode. But when I switch to a different page and back, the switch appears to look like you have not turned it on, even though the variable that is supposed to change with it, actually did get remembered.

I was wondering how I can make it using html, css and javascript, such that the page sees that if the variable has the "on" value, it will always display the switch as if it were on, and always appear to be in the "off" state if that is not the case.

Here is the code I am using:

Javascript:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      ProgramState = "off";
      put("weekProgramState", "week_program_state", ProgramState);
      console.log(ProgramState);
    } else {
      ProgramState = "on";
      put("weekProgramState", "week_program_state", ProgramState);
      console.log(ProgramState);
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 27px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(20px);
  transform: translateX(20px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3> Program Override
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label> </h3>
```

Comment: read cookies...

Comment: Also what is `put`?

Comment: put is a function that we got from the assignment I'm doing this for, it puts the data to the server. It's not important for the question I think, so I didn't include what it meant. Also, what do you mean with "read cookies..."?

Comment: read about JavaScript cookies to save the current state while navigating to other pages.

Comment: isn't there a way to read the data of ProgramState from the server(which I can using a function given), and depending on the value of ProgramState, make the switch appear either in the "on" or "off" position, without having to use the javascript cookies?

Comment: yes there is. try session or database

Comment: session? database? can you provide a link to what you are talking about? I'm new to programming with javascript, html and css, so I actually don't know what exactly you are refering to, and don't really know what I have to do in general.

Comment: which server side language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using only client-side functionalities, then you will either use [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), [localStorage](https://gist.github.com/yeco/288485) or sessionStorage.

If you decide to work with Javascript cookies, then you will need to work with `document.cookie`. When you set its value, you can set parameters and expiration date. Via the parameters you can establish a way to store information and reload it, via an `onoff` parameter, for instance. By default, Javascript cookies will expire when the user closes the browser. Helpful functions:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

and

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

You can decide to use a library to help you if you aim for simplicity, or you can write your own. Somce of the libraries are [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and [CookieHandler](https://gist.github.com/yeco/288485).

If you decide to use localStorage, then you will work with `localStorage.setItem("yourKey", "yourValue")` to store values and `localStorage.getItem("yourKey")` to load values. If you itend to remove items, then `localStorage.removeItem("yourKey")` will be quite handy. Items stored in `localStorage` will not expire. `sessionStorage` is very similar in concept and usage to `localStorage`, with the most notable difference being that `sessionStorage` will expire when the session expires.

Otherwise, if you want to store the state using the server, then you will either need to store the state in a [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) or a file on server-side, however, using a database is clearly superior than storing the data in files on server-side. Either way you will go, from the web-page you will need to post your changes either using an [HTML form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) or [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), handle the request on server-side at application level and then on page load and/or the [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) of your request handle the state of your page. If your user is able to change the state of the pages for other users, then you will need server-side in your scenario, or if you want to persist the data accross different computers/browsers for the same user.

EDIT

As for your particular case, you can do something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("ProgramState", "on");
```

and then on page load, you will be able to set the state of your ui, using the `localStorage.getItem("ProgramState") === "on"` formula

Comment: I can get the value of ProgramState from the server, I've figured that much out. How can I make the switch display in the right way? I don't really understand how I can make the switch display differently based on the value of ProgramState. What do I need to write in CSS, HTML, or Javascript in order to show the right state of the switch?

Comment: @JoJoDeath You will need to give me the source-code of put, the server-side language you are using and the way you correctly set ProgramState if you want a detailed answer.